# How to generate future date and time for postman request

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-pre-request-script

```js
{
    "name": "IronMan",
    "phone_number": "555555555",
    "number_of_guest": 10,
    "tables": [
        2
    ],
    "reservation_start_at": "2020-10-15T10:00:00.861873Z",
    "reservation_end": "2020-10-15T11:00:00.861873Z"
}
```

I am stuck at step where I need to generate future date and time with time zone to send a postman request. The request is about a reservation feature.

On the request body,a key-value is,

```
"reservation_start_at": "2020-10-15T10:00:00.861873Z"
```

My question is, how do I generate future date and time for each request?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: how far into the future? change `2020-10-15T10:00:00.861873Z` to `2020-10-15T10:00:01.861873Z` - now it's 1 second into the future ... similarly for minuts, hours, days months and years

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Future means, lets say tomorrow or 1 week later. I have tried using monet.js with add. But the issue I am facing is mainly, I want a future date, like
18th October 2 PM in string format.

but using the moment.js add (7, 'days') I can only get 7 days in future..but I don't know how would I get the 2 PM or 3PM at that future date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following in postman's pre-request script:

```
var moment = require('moment');

const yearsInTheFuture = 1;
const monthsInTheFuture = 2;
const daysInTheFuture = 3;
const hours = 12;
const minutes = 34;
const seconds = 56;
const milliseconds = 789;
const durationInDays = 7;

const reservation_start_at = moment()
    .add(yearsInTheFuture, 'years')
    .add(monthsInTheFuture, 'months')
    .add(daysInTheFuture, 'days')
    .hours(hours)
    .minutes(minutes)
    .seconds(seconds)
    .millisecond(milliseconds);

reservation_end = moment()
    .add(yearsInTheFuture, 'years')
    .add(monthsInTheFuture, 'months')
    .add(daysInTheFuture + durationInDays, 'days')
    .hours(hours)
    .minutes(minutes)
    .seconds(seconds)
    .millisecond(milliseconds);

console.log("reservation_start_at: " + reservation_start_at);
console.log("reservation_end: " + reservation_end);

pm.environment.set("reservation_start_at ", reservation_start_at);
pm.environment.set("reservation_end", reservation_end);
```

It will set the environment variables `reservation_start_at` and `reservation_end`, which you then can access in the request body:

```
{
   "name":"IronMan",
   "phone_number":"555555555",
   "number_of_guest":10,
   "tables":[
      2
   ],
   "reservation_start_at":"{{reservation_start_at}}",
   "reservation_end":"{{reservation_end}}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below script to generate today's date + 10 days

```
  var moment = require('moment');
    pm.environment.set("futuredate", moment().add(10, 'day').format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```